# Converting the nvarchar value to data type integer

Tags: sql

I just started taking a course in SQL for class and I got the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'ewew' to data type int.

I have a table with players names, addresses and zipcodes.

What I am trying to do is get a list of Basketball Players from the following `PostalCode`, which is 75045.

This is how I wrote my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[BasketballPlayers]
WHERE [PostalCode] = 75045
```

Can somebody explain what may be going on?

Comment: `WHERE [PostalCode] = '75045'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing a string `[PostalCode]` with a number `75045` so it tries to convert both values to the same type, in this case, the numeric type int. Unfortunately, "ewew" is cannot be converted to a number.

What you need to do is compare both as strings so:

```
SELECT*

FROM [dbo].[BasketballPlayers]

WHERE [PostalCode] = '75045'
```

This allows you to compare both as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `TRY_CAST` which will return a valid conversion or `NULL` when trying to make a invalid conversion (*string to int*)

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[BasketballPlayers]
WHERE TRY_CAST([PostalCode] as INT) = 75045
```

---

Example:

```
TRY_CAST('ewew' as INT) = NULL
TRY_CAST('75045' as INT) = 75045
```